# iPhone app freezes when parsing XML

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser, nsthread, nsautoreleasepool

My app freezes whenever I parse an XML feed.

I have tried calling this instead:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(parseXML) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

which calls:

```
-(void) parseXML {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
    [pool drain]; 
}
```

but my app has become quite unstable as a result...the iPhone Simulator just crashed with no error warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than calling :

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(parseXML) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

you should call :

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(parseXML) withObject:nil]
```

Your UI is freezing because you are doing lengthy operations in UI Thread.

Comment: I get this error: 
[Switching to thread 12547]
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
[Switching to thread 12547]

Comment: Now I am getting this: 
Debugger stopped.
Program exited with status value:0.

Comment: it seems the next problem is because of some other code, if you can share it here i can look into it.